# AdBlock CSS rules do not work globally?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, css, adblock

```
Windows 10
Chrome, Version 60.0.3112.113 (Official Build) (64-bit)
AdBlock, VERSION 3.15.0
```

I used the AdBlock "Block An Ad On this Page" menu item to create a base rule to block Taboola ads on Mashable.com. Then, I modified the rule to use a "starts with" CSS syntax:

```
mashable.com##DIV[id^="taboola-"]
```

It works perfectly.  However, if I remove the mashable.com hostname, the rule no longer works.

```
##DIV[id^="taboola-"]
```

I tried other variations, which also seem to work when a hostname is specified, but fail to work when the hostname is removed.

```
##.trc-content-sponsored vs. mashable.com##.trc-content-sponsored
##DIV[id^="trc_wrapper"] vs. mashable.com##DIV[id^="trc_wrapper"]
```

I may have missed something in the docs, but I thought that a rule that is not qualified with a hostname is supposed to be applied to all pages. Can anyone tell me how to apply such rules globally, across all web pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EasyList](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/easylist.txt)  contains the filter `@@||mashable.com^$generichide` which disables global element hiding rules on mashable.com. The `$generichide` filter option has been introduced to counter anti-adblocking measures by preventing ad blocker detection scripts to check for the effect of global filters.

Sources:

- Announcement: [New filter options $generichide and $genericblock](https://adblockplus.org/development-builds/new-filter-options-generichide-and-genericblock)
- Documentation: [adblockplus.org/filters#options](https://adblockplus.org/filters#options)